# Custom Object Detail Filter on Sharing

Tags: sharing, list-view

I am trying to show the list view from the User & Groups Sharing page on a custom object in a visualforce page. Currently I have the following code:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:enhancedList ListId="00Bi0000005JGuU" customizable="false" height="600" rowsPerPage="25"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

When I try and go to the page it states that "CustomObjectSharingDetailFilter does not exist" - Makes sense because it doesn't know what record I'm trying to view.  How can I pass the record parameter/view filter to the view?  I tried putting it into the URL with "?parentId=a05i0000009CCBF" which is what it has normally when I go to the sharing page but that doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your Listview Id ?The ListID will hold List view Id .

Comment: My list ID is 00Bi0000005JGuU - this was the fcf00Bi0000005JGuU number on the list.